# How can I get my second container beneath my background video?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div element that is the size of the page. I want the users to click the "reviews" button and it automatically scroll down and lock on to a div element that takes the size of the screen. The only thing I need help with is getting this div under the "Homescreen"/background video. When I try and add a title for the next div and create a background it just overlays the home video as opposed to being scrollable. Is there some CSS properties that I have that is causing it to be an overlay? As opposed to making the website scrollable?

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <video id="background-video" class="video-background" autoplay loop muted>
        <source
          src="/Users/julianvazquez/Desktop/cyborgs/assets/cloudyy.mp4"
          type="video/mp4"
        />
      </video>
      <ul class="nav-area">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <br />
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="welcome-text" id="welcome-text">
        <h1>
          Cyber <br />
          Angels
        </h1>

        <button class="glowing-btn">
          <span class="glowing-txt"
            >Rev<span class="faulty-letter">iew</span>s</span
          >
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>What are customers saying?</h2>
    </div>

  </body>
```

these are my properties for the container and body elements

```
#background-video {
          position:fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100vw;
          height: 100vh;
          object-fit: cover;
          z-index: -1;
        }

        .container{

          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100vw;
          height: 100vh;
          object-fit: cover;
          z-index: -1;
          
        }
html,
        body {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        body {
          min-height: 100vh;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          background: black;
        }
```

I've attempted rearranging the way the div elements are used and the order. I tried adjusting the properties of the container to ensure non of the properties are causing the opening screen to not be scroll able. I tried adding padding+ margin from the top. None of these did any adjustments. I do have a button that has some complex css on it that produces a flickering effect, I am convinced that it is something in that code causing it . But first I want to rule out that is not anything in the body,container, and background classes.

Answer (score 0):

The `position: fixed` declaration in the `#background-video` rule is what is responsible for taking the video out of the layout "flow" and having the following elements overlayed.

Furthermore, `overflow: hidden` in the `html, body` rule would also prevent scrolling.

Here is your webpage with the aforementioned declarations removed. You'll notice elements are no longer overlaying the video and the page can be scrolled.

```css
#background-video {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <video id="background-video" class="video-background" autoplay loop muted>
      <source
        src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
        type="video/mp4"
      />
    </video>
    <ul class="nav-area">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <br />
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="welcome-text" id="welcome-text">
      <h1>
        Cyber <br />
        Angels
      </h1>

      <button class="glowing-btn">
        <span class="glowing-txt"
          >Rev<span class="faulty-letter">iew</span>s</span
        >
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>What are customers saying?</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```